# How to indent enumerate in beamer

Tags: beamer, enumerate, indentation

Hi i ask beacuse the previuos questions are 10 year old and non of comments are working for me, i want to change the indent as it actually look to much to the left in reference to the paragraph

[image]

The code is like:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.0]{beamerposter}
\usetheme{gemini}
\usecolortheme{nott}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\geometry{papersize={84cm,118cm}}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{columns}[t]
\separatorcolumn

\begin{column}{\colwidth}

  \begin{block}

  \begin{enumerate[($i$)] 
    \item
    \item
    \item
\end{enumerate}
\end{block}
% ...
\end{column}
% ...
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gemini` theme seems to think that it is a good idea to overwrite beamer's redefinition of lists and for some inexplicable reason it will do so by using the second level `\leftmarginii` for the first level list.

This means that unlike for all normal beamer themes, you have to change the margin for the first level enumerate like this:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.0]{beamerposter}
\usetheme{gemini}
\usecolortheme{nott}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\setlength{\leftmarginii}{2cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
  text
  \begin{enumerate}[(i)]
    \item test
    \item test
    \item test
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks it looks perfect, and what an eye to catch the problem

Comment: @FranciscaAguayo You're welcome!